# javascript - object [] notation

Tags: javascript, html, object

Started learning `javascript` and currently going thru object topic.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h3>object prop access</h3>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="test"></p>
<script>

    var foo = {unique_prop: 1}, bar = {unique_prop: 2}, object = {};
    object[foo] = 'value1';

    //console.log(object[bar]);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Object property:"+object[bar];
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Object property object[foo]:"+object[foo];

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I run this program it prints value "`value1`" , "`value1`" in separate lines.
My question is there is no property name "`bar`" defined for "`object`" then why `object[bar]` prints value "`value1`" - which is assigned to `object[foo]`.

--Divyesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because an object property has a key and a value. The key is always a string. When you try to set a key for a value for which that key is a variable and it as an object, it will have the `.toString` method of the object/variable called which is this case is will return `[object Object]`

so `bar` and `foo` will be equivalent when converted to a string.

So, you can think of it as accessing the object like this `object["[object Object]"`]

`bar.toString() // "[object Object]"`

`foo.toString() // "[object Object]"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested this toString() method behaviour by printing object "Foo" and "Bar". However my question is code above sets property of object[foo] = "value1". There is no property "Bar" defined for object "Object". How can the object[Bar] = "value1" too?

Comment: I understood your point now.. Thanks a lot. I see that basically object[foo] or object[bar] is equivalent to object["[object Object]"]. So if object[foo] = "value1" so it object[bar].